# Pagination - UnsupportedOperationException while accessing to the second page using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to add pagination to my current application. To do that, I have the following code:

MyEntity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MY_ENTITY_1")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="P_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "C_CODEBRANCHE")
    private Integer codeBranche;

    // ...
}
```

MyEntityRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {
}
```

MyServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {    
    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

    @Override
    public Page<MyEntity> getEntities(Pageable pageable) {
        return myEntityRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

And MyResource.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyResource {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/myentity")
    public Page<MyEntity> getEntities(Pageable pageable) {
        return myService.getEntities(pageable);
    }
}
```

When I call "/myentity", I have 20 results, and that's normal.

When I call "/myentity?page=0&size=10", I have 10 results.

But, when I call "/myentity?page=1&size=10", I have the following issue:

> ERROR 6864 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]
>   : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with
>   path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception
>   is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: query result offset is not
>   supported] with root cause
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: query result offset is not
>   supported     at
>   org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect$1.processSql(DB2400Dialect.java:26)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>   ...

I really have no idea what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps you faced this bug [HHH-10489](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10489).
this bug has fixed at Hibernate 5.2.4.Final, then you should update Hibernate to that or more late version.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your application.yml:

spring: jpa: properties: hibernate: legacy_limit_handler: true